# Hive Execution Job is not going to complete after acceptance

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, jobs

After trying all solutions of stackoverflow in hive  when i had putted one query of wordcount by following these tutorials [tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/word-count-program-using-r-spark-map-reduce-pig-hive-python-sahu). My job is not going to complete .

Screendshot of problem is :-
[image]
My Hive Query is:-

```
SELECT word, COUNT(*) FROM doc LATERAL VIEW explode(split(text, ' ')) doc as word GROUP BY word;
```

My mapered.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
 </property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

My yarn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>1100</value>
  <description>Amount of physical memory, in MB, that can be allocated for containers.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>250</value>
</property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.min-healthy-disks</name>
     <value>0.0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
     <value>100.0</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```